# Engine stops on turn signal light

Tags: chevrolet, impala

I have a Chevy Impala 2005. While driving or in parking mode, if I use the side light, the engine comes to halt (i.e the engine stops). What is the real problem?
The hazard light,AC, headlight everything works well.

Comment: The problem is electrical.  I suspect either your ignition switch or a poor earth somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by side light @SulavTimsina? The turn signal?

Comment: @GdD yes the turn signal. Sorry.

Comment: What do mean by parking mode? Does this happen when in park or neutral?

Comment: @GdD yes.when the engine is running. But this happens most of the time and not always

Comment: It may be some electrical problem like @SteveMatthews said. I have a somewhat similar issue with my motorcycle. That caused due to the poor earth connection.